# Flutter: Use Navigator with TabBar and TabBarView

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to understand the class Navigator.

A Navigator Route seem to always return a new widget but what if I want to manage the `TabBar` and `TabBarView` so that each Tab when tapped or swipe on, will be pushed to the Navigator stack, I don't find a what to do that.

On a more general case, can I react to a route change without creating a new widget but instead taking another action like scrolling to a specific item in a `listView`?

I've tried recreating the entire app structure every time but doing this way I don't have the nice default animation and, also, doesn't seem a good approach to me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! A little more detail would be great - what is the specific use case of pushing the views of the tabbar to the stack? Typically, you would have the tab bar, and then each of the views in the tab would be a navigation controller with it's own stack. This is because typically, each view of the tab will have a seperate user flow (Think Spotify - Search, Profile, etc) and have each of them all munched into the same nav stack would be a bad user experience.

Comment: You can observe changing tabs by TabController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WillPopScope widget and its onWillPop to catch the back button pressure and handle it yourself. Find more info here https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html

> On a more general case, can I react to a route change without creating
>   a new widget but instead taking another action like scrolling to a
>   specific item in a listView?

This looks more specific rather than general. However, you do need to set a `ScrollController` in your `ListView` and let it scroll the list for you to the desired point. A simple example function returning to top:

```
class MyFancyClass extends StatelessWidget{
...
ScrollController _scrollController;
...
@override
Widget build(BuildContext Context){
  return ....
  new ListView(
    ...
    controller: _scrollController,
    ...
}

void _toTop() {
  _scrollController.animateTo(
    0.0,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    curve: Curves.ease,
  );
}
```

Check https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html for more details and behaviors. In case you want the back button to bring you to the top:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: _onTop,
    child: 
      ...
    ),
  );
}
```

Concerning the tab behavior I suggest you to read https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TabController-class.html to better understand how to implement what you have in your mind.